# How to use macro to highlight inserted content in a word doc?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to highlight all the inserted/added content(from the tracked changes) in a word file. How am I suppose to use macro to find all the inserted/added content? For example, in the below screenshot:
[image]

the words `blue` `yellow` `And amusing` `pink` and `hello` should all be highlighted after running the macro. And the macro should also be able to work smoothly when running a relatively big Word file with all different tracked changes. Below is the macro content to highlight the content to be yellow, but I don't know how to find the inserted content as I'm not familiar with Macro. = =

```
The Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the Revisions Object (Word)

```
Sub HighlightInsertedRevision()

   Dim myRevision As Revision
   Dim currentDoc As Word.Document

   Set currentDoc = Application.ActiveDocument

   'Set the selection range
   currentDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

   'Optimise for loop
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Loop all revisions in current document
   For Each myRevision In currentDoc.Revisions
       With myRevision
           'Check if revision type is inserted revision
           If .Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
               .Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
           End If
       End With
   Next

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

More Information on MSDN: [Revisions Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/revisions-object-word)

Comment: hi @keenlearner, thank you so much for the help! I'll test your code hopefully today and give you any feedback I have. :)

Comment: Hi @keenlearner, I just tried the macro, it works great on small files with very few inserted content, but when I run it on a word doc with 20k words and a whole bunch of tracked changes, the macro is just running forever,  leaving my WORD freezing there. Is this something that we can overcome/fix in macro?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code above, can you add Application.ScreenUpdating = True and Application.ScreenUpdating = false? Let me know if it still does not improve the performance. Also, what version of word document are you using?